# Auto-mounting the 2nd internal HD

Tags: linux-mint, fstab, automounting, uuid, noatime

I'm editing the fstab file to automount my secondary HD and I would like to know how to setup the 'noatime' in the command line.

The command I have so far is:

```
UUID=DEVICEID   /PATH        ntfs-3g rw,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=0022,fmask=0022      0       2
```

Where should I add the 'noatime' command in this case? Any thoughts are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`noatime` is an option. Comma seperated options are the fourth field in /etc/fstab:

```
UUID=DEVICEID   /PATH        ntfs-3g rw,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=0022,fmask=0022,noatime      0       2
```

https://www.howtoforge.com/reducing-disk-io-by-mounting-partitions-with-noatime

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info@smangum. Also, does it matter if the spaces in the command line are placed with the Tab key or just one hit on the space bar?

Comment: Tabs are definitely ol. One thought is you may not be filling in the UUID and the path, with the actual values. DEVICEID almost certainly  wont work, you would need to locate the uuid of the device you want to mount.
/PATH is probably not the path either.
You should ensure all the directories are on the path.

In addtion, consider checking journalctl and googling any errors you see, this may give a clue as to why it isn't mounting.

Answer (score 0):

ok I just ran that command:

```
UUID=DEVICEID   /PATH        ntfs-3g rw,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=0022,fmask=0022,noatime      0       2
```

Then reboot the system and the 2nd HD is not automounting. Just to check I also ran:

```
cat /etc/fstab | grep DRIVENAME
```

And I can see that it is mounted. Does anyone knows why the system is not automounting the 2nd HD?

Comment: I think it would be useful to run the command `lsblk -f` - this will reveal your block devices, their UUID's and their mount points.

Comment: Yes, I ran `lsblk -f` and could see all the block devices. Thanks for sharing the idea. In the end, since the 2nd HD is automounting at boot but not showing under the "Devices" section in the file manager, I created a bookmark to the automounted HD folder that I created and everything is working fine now. Thanks everybody for the help, much appreciated.